# Json can not be parsed when received dynamically (using socket.io)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, socket.io

I am receiving json-datas which is 100% correct formatted json data.

My problem is,

when I run the following code it works:

```
var data = {"datas":[{"matts":{"active":"1","status":"off"},"config":null,"adapters":[]}}]};

console.dir(data); // it works.
```

but when I receive the same data on socket.io like following code, its not working:

```
_liveSock.on('sm', function(data)
{
    console.log(data); // I am receiving the data correctly. 
    console.dir(data); // But I cant display the data.
});
```

Both codes are almost the same logic, only the second one is received dynamically.

When I try to use console.dir(data); on second code, it gives this error:

```
there is no kind object
```

(btw. I am using Firefox/Firebug)

Is there another method or way to use dynamically received json datas?

Thank you!

Comment: Could you make sure that what you posted accurately reflects what you've really tried?

Comment: Please provide the code you use for sending the data and the output you get from console.log(data) on the receiving end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `console.dir()` until you have **parsed** the value.

```
console.dir(JSON.parse(data));
```

The `JSON` facility is not available in older browsers.  You can find parsers [online](http://json.org).

Comment: console.dir(JSON.parse(data));
it still say there is no kind object. On the last version of firefox

Comment: It's there in my Firefox (14.0.1).

Comment: Yes when you use var data=.. etc.. but not when you receive dynamically.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the string comes from. A string is a string.

Comment: To clarify: `JSON.parse('{"name": "value"}')` works fine in up-to-date versions of Firefox.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14587/discussion-between-vury-and-pointy)